# Coma o punto después de palabras como hola, sí, no

Tags: puntuación

En el caso de vocativos, se usa coma después de palabras como *hola*, *sí*, *no*; por ejemplo, se dice:

> Hola, amigo.
>
> (¿Ya hiciste la tarea?) - Sí, mamá. / No, mamá.

Sin embargo, ¿qué signo de puntuación se usa cuando después de alguna de estas palabras se escribe una oración? Por ejemplo, ¿qué oración es correcta?

> Hola, ¿cómo estás? / Hola. ¿Cómo estás?
>
> (¿Vas a ir a la fiesta?) - Sí, llegaré a las 8. / Sí. Llegaré a las 8.
>
> (¿Vas a ir a la fiesta?) - No, no iré. / No. No iré.

Answer (score 3):

En [este blog](http://grammatikus.blogspot.com.ar/2011/06/preguntas-36-40.html) encontré lo que creo es una respuesta bastante acertada a la primera pregunta:

> Hola, ¿cómo estás? / Hola. ¿Cómo estás?

"Hola" es una interjección. Al respecto, el blog mencionado dice:

> *La interjección es una clase de palabra que forma expresiones exclamativas con las que se manifiestan sentimientos, impresiones o reacciones afectivas, se induce a la acción o se apela al interlocutor (entre las interjecciones de carácter apelativo se incluyen también las fórmulas de saludo y despedida). **Las interjecciones y las locuciones interjectivas pueden formar por sí mismas un enunciado o insertarse en otro**, pero conservando en él su autonomía sintáctica y significativa, **de ahí que se escriban entre comas, o entre una coma y otro signo si aparecen en posición inicial o final**. En el ejemplo que nos ocupa, si se prescindiera del vocativo y solo se usaran la interjección y la interrogante, quedaría: "Hola, ¿cómo estás?".*

El blog está en lo correcto en cuanto a la posibilidad de que las interjecciones sean independientes o estén insertas en otros enunciados. Si pueden formar enunciados autónomos, a mi entender el blog omite decir que también pueden estar separadas por puntos:

- Hola. ¿Cómo estás? (La diferencia en el habla será, obviamente, una mayor pausa si se utiliza punto.)

En cuanto a los adverbios afirmativo y negativo "sí" y "no", ambas puntuaciones son también posibles **siempre que el adverbio se refiera al verbo de la oración que sigue**. Si usamos una coma, el adverbio refuerza el sentido afirmativo o negativo de la oración. Si usamos un punto:

a) el adverbio reemplaza toda la oración objeto de la pregunta (un caso de elipsis), si es que el verbo de la pregunta es diferente del de la oración que sigue, o

b) en caso de que los verbos sean iguales, se puede usar punto simplemente para marcar una pausa mayor:

A. ¿**Vas a ir** a la fiesta?

B. Sí (= **Voy a ir**). LLegaré a las 8. (La coma en este caso seria incorrecta, pues equivaldría a yuxtaponer dos verbos: ?Voy a ir, llegaré a las 8.)

B'. Sí, **iré** con gusto. (= Sí que iré, y lo haré con gusto.)

A. ¿**Vas a ir** a la fiesta?

B. No, no iré. (El primer "no" refuerza el segundo.)

B'. No. No iré. (El primer "no" reemplaza a "No iré". El hablante hace una pausa mayor entre ambos enunciados, como si dijera: *No iré. No iré de ninguna manera*.)

Comment: Y aquí se produce un problema entre gramática y la forma correcta de escribir una frase.  
"Hoooola pooo!"
"Hola-qué-tal!"
En una novela, si tuviera que escribir uno de estos, no dudaría en sacar la coma.

Comment: @Billeeb La gramática establece la forma correcta de escribir frases y oraciones. No entiendo la oposición.

Comment: No me he opuesto, sólo hice un comentario. Es verdad lo ue dices pero piensa en cómo escribirías tú las frases que puse arriba. Si escribes: Hola. Po. U Hola. ¿Qué tal?

Comment: @Billeeb La opción es escribir coma o punto. No es una opción escribir guiones o ningún signo. La escritura tiene normas propias y no es una mera imitación de la lengua oral.

Comment: A eso iba con mi comentario. Ya vi que escribí lo mismo dos veces.