# Can a question mark come inside a sentence?

Tags: puntuación

`Hola, ¿hablas inglés?`?

The above sentence is provided as a correct solution in my Duolingo Spanish course.

My question is why the ¿ does not come in the beginning of the sentence.
If it were `Hola. ¿Hablas inglés?`, it makes sense to me because they are two separate sentences.
But the provided solution is one sentence and the beginning question mark is located inside a sentence, not at the beginning of the sentence.

I wonder if this is the custom in the Spanish sentence.

Comment: You can find the answer to your question here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23718/coma-o-punto-despu%C3%A9s-de-palabras-como-hola-s%C3%AD-no

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin and usage of "¿" and "¡"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-and-usage-of-and)

Comment: because "hola" is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a sentence there can me many pieces that, together, form the whole sentence, but they're not necessarily related. They can serve different purposes.
For instance, **"Hola,"** is a greeting, and **"¿hablas inglés?"** is the actual question. "Hola" is not part of the question, so it's made very clear by the **"¿ ?"** where it begins and where it ends.
I know it sounds obvious in this small sentence with a comma, but in a long paragraph it can be extremely useful, especially if reading out loud.
It doesn't necessarily need to have a period or even a comma for this break to occur.
Look at this example:

`Iba caminando por la calle y pensé ¿por qué está tan enojada?`

Notice that a simple change in thought, or meaning can trigger the question mark to show that a question is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

> b) Los signos de interrogación y de exclamación se escriben pegados a la primera y la última palabra del **período** que enmarcan. [...]

> c) Tras los signos de cierre **puede colocarse cualquier signo de puntuación**, salvo el punto. Lógicamente, cuando la interrogación o la exclamación terminan un enunciado y sus signos de cierre equivalen a un punto. [...]

> d) Los signos de apertura (¿ ¡) se han de colocar justo donde empieza la pregunta o la exclamación, **aunque no se corresponda con el inicio del enunciado**; en ese caso, la interrogación o la exclamación se inician con minúscula. [...]

> f) Cuando se escriben seguidas varias preguntas o exclamaciones breves, **se pueden considerar como oraciones independientes, o bien como partes de un único enunciado.**

[El Señor RAE](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n) te está dando indicios de que no tiene por qué siempre suceder lo que estás planteando; los signos de interrogación acompañan a un *período*, ni siquiera una *cláusula*, ni siquiera una *oración*, ni siquiera un *enunciado*. Desconozco las traducciones exactas al inglés de todos esos términos. Pero creo que parte de lo que contribuye a la confusión es la creencia equivocada de que la oración tiene que acabar en un punto, cuando éste representa una pausa—nada más te dice 'tomá aire'—;y así, por analogía, de que los signos de interrogación deben encerrar a una oración cuando tranquilamente podrían incluso hasta acompañar a un simple sintagma como ocurre en el caso de las preguntas confirmatorias, ¿o no?

Answer (score 0):

La puntuación es esencial a la hora de comunicarse en una lengua y su uso correcto es igual de importante. Sin embargo, no existen las mismas normas de puntuación en todos los idiomas. Acciones habituales como redactar una carta, introducir un diálogo o escribir números decimales tienen diferencias de puntuación en inglés y español.

En español la forma más adecuada de escribir esta frase es **¡Hola!, ¿hablas inglés?** Sí el inicio de la pregunta no coincide con el enunciado, la secuencia interrogativa empieza con minúscula **¡Hola!, ¿hablas inglés?**; si la pregunta abre el enunciado, entonces empieza con mayúscula **¡Hola! ¿Hablas inglés?**

[image]

Después de un signo de interrogación que cierra la frase, se escribe en mayúscula, siempre y cuando no haya otro signo, en este caso, al existir **una coma** (,), se escribe en minúscula. **¡Hola!, ¿hablas inglés?**

Otro caso distinto, pero relacionado; **¡Hola! Pedro. ¿Hablas inglés?**

[image]

La letra mayúscula, indica el inicio de los enunciados, y el punto, marca su fin. Sin embargo, la función de indicar el fin del enunciado no es solo del punto: también los puntos suspensivos (...), el signo de cierre de interrogación (?) y el signo de cierre de exclamación (!) pueden desempeñar esa función delimitadora.

*https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/ortografia-de-los-signos-de-interrogacion-y-exclamacion*

[image]

En español, el punto (.) indica una pausa. El punto y coma (;) indica una pausa o separación menor que la del punto. La coma (,) expresa una pausa menor que la del punto y coma (;) y que la del punto (.)

Answer (score -1):

What it's important to understand is that Duolingo is programmed in a way that Symbols are often omitted.

In Spanish we're starting to use less the `¿` at the beginning of a sentence, even tho it needs to be used in formal situations.

To answer your question, yes. It can be used inside a sentence. The `¿` doesn't mean a sentence is starting, here's an example:

In english you'd say:
"It's late, are you coming?"

And it's just one sentence. Same in Spanish:
"Es tarde, ¿estás viniendo?"

Comment: I struggle to see how your English example has anything to do with the question as we do not have punctuation at the beginning of our sentences except for quotation marks.